# Injective representation of nonabelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $H$ be a nonabelian group of order $pq$ where $q<p$ are prime. Then show that $H$ has an injective representation $\rho:H \to GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$.

What I have shown so far is that if $H$ is a group of order $pq$, then it is either $C_{pq}$ or it is $C_p \rtimes_{\phi} C_q$ where $\phi:C_q \to Aut(C_p)$ is injective, so because $H$ is nonabelian it must be the latter. However I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: By "injective" here do you mean "faithful"? (There's a mild collision of terminology here - you might mean an injective object in the category of representations over $\mathbb{F}_p$.)

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

There exists only  one $H_p$ Sylow subgroup of order $p$, otherwise you have at least $(p+1)(p-1)=p^2-1>pq$. This imples that $H_p$ is normal. Let $H_q$ be a Sylow subgroup of order $q$, $H_q$ acts non trivially on $H_p$ by conjugation since $G$ is not commutative, since $H_q$ acts by linear maps of the vector space $\mathbb{F_q}=H_p$, we deduce that $H_q\subset \mathbb{F}^*_p =\mathbb{F}_p-\{0\}$.

This implies that you can embed $G$ in $Gl_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ has a subgroup of
$\pmatrix{a&c\cr 0&1}$ where $H_p$ is the subgroup $\pmatrix{1&c\cr 0&1}$ and $H_q$ is a subgroup of $\pmatrix{a&0\cr 0&1}$.